# inRange is not defined? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on an extension that will make a popup alert at a specified time. While trying to run it, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: inRange is not defined`  I'm confused, as inRange works in other projects, just not this one. I haven't found much to help me debug this. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Code:

```
date = new Date()
currentHour = date.getHours()
currentMinute = date.getMinutes()
currentTime = currentHour + (0.01 * currentMinute)

function popup_al (){
    if (inRange(currentTime,11.18,11.20)){
        return alert("Alert")
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `inRange` supposed to be? It's not a standard JS function.

Comment: Don't use floating point to represent dates and times. You'll run into problems due to floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: Oops, sorry I'm fairly new to js. I forgot to define this correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Also thank you Barmar for the help on that too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself, I thought inRange was a JS function, but it was not. I later defined inRange as

```
function inRange(number, min, max) {
    return (number >= min && number <= max)
}
```